# Scanning file into an array of structures in C

Tags: c

My program isn't reading past the first line of my file. I have the file

```
John 22 67 
Rickard 31 100 
Andrew 21 34 
Sarah 20 80
```

Attempting to read with:

```
void loadPeople(char fileName[],Person people[],int * length){
  FILE *fptr = fopen("fileName", "r");
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    fscanf(fptr, "%s", people[i].name);
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &people[i].age);
    fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &people[i].score);
    fclose(fptr);
  }
  return;
}
```

The program is only reading the first line of the file into person[0] and not beyond.

Comment: `if (fscanf(fptr, "%s %d %lf", people[i].name, &people[i].age, &people[i].score) != 3) { fputs ("error: invalid format.\n", stderr); break; }` (after fixing your `fclose()` problem) ALWAYS Validate the return of any of the `scanf` family of functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the file after reading the first record. Move `fclose()` out of the loop.

You should also check that the file was opened successfully, by checking that `fptr` is not `NULL` before looping through the file.

Comment: Thanks! Wow I feel dumb.